# open popup from another popup (double popup)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I am using fancybox for single popup now. Working with Mvc 4.5 ASP.Net . Is this possible to get (2nd popup)popup from another (1st popup)popup , also (2nd popup)popup contains form where value is passed and saved ... after saved 1st popup should be open not the page main page.  I want popup over another popup so can someone help me.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, not at least with fancybox since you can only have one modal box opened at that time

Answer (score -1):

## HTML CODE

> <ul id="nav">
> <li class="site-name"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
>     <li class="facebook"><a href="#">Facebook</a>
>         <ul>
>         <li><a href="#">Facebook Pages</a></li>
>         <li><a href="#">Facebook Groups</a></li>
>         </ul>
>     </li>
>     <li class="yahoo"><a href="#">Yahoo</a>
>         <ul>
>         <li><a href="#">Yahoo Games &raquo;</a>            
>             <ul>
>                 <li><a href="#">Board Games</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#">Card Games</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#">Puzzle Games</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#">Skill Games &raquo;</a>
>                 <ul>
>                     <li><a href="#">Yahoo Pool</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#">Chess</a></li>
>                 </ul>
>                 </li>
>             </ul>
>         </li>
>         <li><a href="#">Yahoo Search</a></li>
>         <li><a href="#">Yahoo Answsers</a></li>
>         </ul>
>     </li>
>     <li class="google"><a href="#">Google</a>
>         <ul>
>         <li><a href="#">Google mail</a></li>
>         <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a></li>
>         <li><a href="#">Google Search &raquo;</a>
>             <ul>
>                 <li><a href="#">Search Images</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#">Search Web</a></li>
>             </ul>
>         </li>
>         </ul>
>     </li>
>     <li class="twitter"><a href="#">Twitter</a>
>             <ul>
>                 <li><a href="#">New Tweets</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#">Compose a Tweet</a></li>
>             </ul>
>     </li>
> </ul>

## CSS CODE

> #nav{
>     height: 39px;
>     border-radius: 3px;
>     min-width:500px;
>     border:1px solid #ddd;
> }   
> #nav li{
>     list-style: none;
>     display: block;
>     float: left;
>     height: 40px;
>     position: relative;
> }
> #nav li a{
>     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
>     margin: 0px 0;
>     line-height: 40px;
>     border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
>     height: 40px;
> }
> #nav ul{
>     padding: 0px;
>     width:170px;
>     border:1px solid #ddd;
> }
> #nav .site-name,#nav .site-name:hover{
>     padding-left: 10px;
>     padding-right: 10px;
>     width: 160px;
> }
> #nav .site-name a{
>     width: 129px;
>     overflow:hidden;
> }
> #nav li a{
>     display: block;
> }
> #nav ul li {
>     border-right:none;
>     border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;
>     width:170px;
>     height:39px;
> }
> #nav ul li a {
>     border-right: none;
>     border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
> }
> /* Sub menus */
> #nav ul{
>     display: none;
>         visibility:hidden;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 40px;
> }
> /* Third-level menus */
> #nav ul ul{
>     top: 0px;
>     left:170px;
>     display: none;
>         visibility:hidden;
>     border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
> }
> /* Fourth-level menus */
> #nav ul ul ul{
>     top: 0px;
>     left:170px;
>     display: none;
>         visibility:hidden;
>     border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
> }
> #nav ul li{
>     display: block;
>         visibility:visible;
> }
> #nav li:hover > ul{
>     display: block;
>         visibility:visible;
> }

## JQUERY CODE

> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $("#nav li").hover(
>     function(){
>         $(this).children('ul').hide();
>         $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
>     },
>     function () {
>         $('ul', this).slideUp('fast');            
>     });
> });

Comment: i m not saying that i need drop down menu .............. this is not what i want ...

Comment: visit this site i think it's helpfull for you http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/09/ajax-php-and-mysql-tutorials

Comment: there is a slight difference between "pop-up" and "drop-down" ;)